# How can I modify attributes in Record Types after container is deployed to production?

Tags: cloudkit

I need to remove / add new attributes to one of my record type, but container is deployed to production yet. Any chance?

As you can see - I hovered over the X button my mouse - it not possible to remove attributes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just make modifications to the development container and then deploy that again to production. See the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/DesigningforCloudKit/DesigningforCloudKit.html

It says: Prior to deploying your app, you migrate your schema and data to the production environment using CloudKit Dashboard. When running against the production environment, the server prevents your app from changing the schema programmatically. You can still make changes with CloudKit Dashboard but attempts to add fields to a record in the production environment result in errors.

Then see the part 'Future Proofing Your Records'

Comment: Thanks the info, and it is not anymore possible to remove attributes :-(

Comment: Then we have to be careful before going to production. :-)

Comment: It does seem that there's no way to dynamically create new record types in or alter existing ones in cloud kit.  Something that I find very limiting at this age of NOSQL backends.  There are course alternatives like storing dynamic data as JSON objects in a NSData attribute.